# Al iniciar servicio junto al SO Android, lo detiene

Tags: android

Estoy Implementando un servicio que arranca cuando el sistema termina de iniciarse, lo estuve probando en un Motorola E4 Plus y funciona sin ningun problema, pero estuve probando la aplicacion en dos telefonos marca Samsung y Huawei, pero el servicio no inicia, solo me aparece el el mensaje que se ha detenido la aplicacion:
Estes es mi monitor de arranque del servicio: la falla en las marcas anteriomente mencionadas esta en la linea: context.startService(Servicio);

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

//Servicio encargado de iniciar el servicio Junto al SO

public class MonitorAlertas extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {//se crea el Intent para iniciar el servicio

        Intent Servicio = new Intent(context,ServicioLectura.class);

        context.startService(Servicio);

    }


}
```

y en el manifest.xml esta declarado de esta forma:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".MonitorAlertas"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".ServicioLectura">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ServicioLectura"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:name=".Inicial">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Agrega el código de ServicioLectura , ahí es donde se encuentra el problema, agrega además que sistema operativo usan tus dispositivos. Acostumbra también agregar el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat

Answer (score 4):

Mi estimado amigo

Te comparto una función que espero te sirva:

```
public void iniciarServicio(Context context, Class servicioIniciar) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, servicioIniciar);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context.startForegroundService(intent1);
    } else {
        context.startService(intent1);
    }
}
```

La puedes usar desde tu `onReceive`, así:

```
    @Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    iniciarServicio(context, ServicioLectura.class);
}
```

Creo que tu problema es que quizás alguno de los dispositivos en los que probaste, la versión de `Android` cambió y alguno fue `Android` 8 y para esta versión, el modo de iniciar un servicio cambia. Otra cosa que quizás debes saber es que a partir de `Android` Oreo, el SO no deja tener servicios en segundo plano si no hay una actividad en primer plano, y el servicio muere cuando se cierra la actividad.

intenta primero esta metodo que te doy, y si no te funciona con gusto seguiremos revisando.

Comment: Hola William, tienes razón en los dispositivos que probé tienen Androide 8, pero por ejemplo como hace Whatsapp para poder tener servicios en segundo plano con estos SO.

Comment: Probare este método a ver como me va, apenas tenga resultados se los muestro nuevamente, para seguir investigando juntos esta novedad de OREO.

Comment: En android 8, se acostumbra utilizar en el manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" /> <!-- para API 28 en adelante-->

Answer (score 1):

En tu `AndroidManifest.xml` es correcta tu configuración :

```
  <receiver android:name=".MonitorAlertas"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Al tener configurado `BOOT_COMPLETED`, este broadcast se transmite una vez después de que el usuario haya terminado de iniciar el dispositivo y esto es correcto:

```
public class MonitorAlertas extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BootUpReceiver";

   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     //se crea el Intent para iniciar el servicio
     Intent Servicio = new Intent(context,ServicioLectura.class);
      context.startService(Servicio);

    }
}
```

Te comparto un ejemplo de [BOOT_COMPLETED](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-start-app-on-BOOT_COMPLETED)

**El problema se encuentra dentro del servicio `ServicioLectura`**

editando... esperando actualización.

Comment: Estuve probando esta alternativa pero aun sigue con el fallo en el arranque, de todas formas muchas gracias por tu participación. Te agradezco mucho.

Answer (score -1):

perdon por tardar tanto en responderte nuevamente.

Como no has compartido tu codigo de tu servicio activo, supongamos por un momento que que tu servicio esta bien codificado, y supongamos tambien que este problema se debe a la version del sistema operativo, para el cual intentaremos trabajar en este enfoque.

Continuando con tu questionamiento te comento lo siguiente:

Dado que tu problema es que Android 8 en adelante no deja tener servicios en segundo plano abiertos, vamos a enfocarnos en soluciones para Android 8 (no le sobran a los android anteriores pero si son necesarios para el OREO en adelante).

Primero te recomiendo que añadas al manifest los permisos de proceso en segundo plano:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" /> <!-- para API 28 en adelante-->
```

Se que esto es para android 9, pero algunos android 8.1 parecen ser rechonchos y sin este permiso prohibe mucho mas el proceso en segundo plano, al colocar este permiso en el manifest, logras que tu servicio ya pueda trabajar en segundo plano, y aquí hemos solucionado un primer problema.

Ahora el segundo problema es evitar que el SO Android lo asesine por su necesidad de ahorrar recursos a la hora de administrar la duración de la batería.

Para esto en un proyecto anterior efectué varias alternativas, las cuales van en el manifest:

tu colocas en tu manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MonitorAlertas"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

esto hace que el tu `MonitorAlertas` arranque el servicio, pero como el OREO es un fanatico de ahorrar bateria, en cualquier momento (mas pronto que tarde) se cerrará tu servicio.

Te presento tres alternativas:
1) Forzar a verificar el sistema para que chequee que si el servicio esta cerrado, lo habra nuevamente, esto lo logras añadiendole al manifest otros permisos:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MonitorAlertas"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

con esto no solo se ejecutará tu `MonitorAlertas` cuando arranque el dispositivo, sino tambien cuando se desconecte o conecte de una red WIFI, cuando se conecte el cargador para darle energia a la bateria (que es algo que hoy en dia se hace muy seguido pues la bateria de los celulares dura cada vez menos), tambien cuando se desconecte el cargador, con todo esto ya estaras batallando con mas fuerza para que si el SO te cierra tu servicio, pues tu lo vuelves a abrir, esto es algo que hoy se hacen en muchas aplicaciones.

2) puedes crear un servicio de recepcion de datos para el FireBase, y lo dejas en espera de recibir información, cuando reciba algun dato por este canal aprovechas para abrir tu servicio en segundo plano, no es curioso que todos los servicios de FireBase no se cierran?, es como si el sistema estuviera mirando que servicios en segundo plano son de firebase y cuales no, para cerrar los que no son de Google (Firebase), cochinos celos. Pero si te aprovechas de esto, podrias usarlo para abrir tu servicio.

3) Otra solución pero es muy drastica es colocar tu servicio en primer plano, con una notificacion permanente en la barra de noificaciones, con esto el servicio tiene la prioridad y al ahorrar la bateria el SO no cerrará el servicio, pero esto es la ultima opcion que debes tener para que el servicio no muera, pues a la mayoria de los usuarios no les gusta esa molesta notificacion permanente y con opciones del SO, lo asesinan manualmente sino lo ven importante, por lo cual no se recomienda en primera opcion.

Espero que estos conocimientos te sean de utilidad, por supuesto hay muchas mas, has tus pruebas y comentanos para ver como mas podriamos ayudarte.

Cordialmente.